# IdentityServer4 how to set server cookie expiration

Tags: cookies, identityserver4

So far I've seen how to set expiration for the client webapp's cookie (thank you v0id):  [IdentityServer4 cookie expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325793/identityserver4-cookie-expiration)

There are actually two cookies used by IdentityServer4 - the client cookie and server cookie ("idsrv").

If I set the client cookie expiration as given here:
[IdentityServer4 cookie expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325793/identityserver4-cookie-expiration/49337801#49337801)
then when I close the browser and go back to a client webapp page where I need to be authorized, I get access denied because the browser session no longer has the server cookie.

So I need a way to set the "idsrv" cookie expiration to be the same as the client.

Currently, the best way I see to set the server cookie (it is being ignored or dropped somehow) is the following code block in the IdentityServer4 host Startup.cs / ConfigureServices() method:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
                options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
            })
```

That should set the cookie's expiration to one year later.  However, in Chrome developer tools under the Application tab, cookies, I see that it still has an expired expiration default date in 1969.

I downloaded the IdentityServer4 project source, removed the nuget package, and added the source project to my solution so I could debug through it.

I see that it gets the expiration I gave it in the ConfigureInternalCookieOptions.cs / Configure() method.  It's matching the DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme inside as well / applying the properties.  I haven't found anything specific to IdentityServer that would ignore the expiration date I've set, but it still has the 1969 expiration.

Edit:  I've attempted to set the cookie persistent in the IdentityServer host's AccountController as follows (interestingly enough, Microsoft has a good article around using authenticationproperties without using AspNet Identity here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x - it is sending information in a cookie, "scheme" is just the cookie name):
In the ExternalLoginCallback():

```
if (id_token != null)
        {
            props = new AuthenticationProperties();
            props.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration);
            props.IsPersistent = true;
            props.StoreTokens(new[] { new AuthenticationToken { Name = "id_token", Value = id_token } });
        }
```

None of the server side cookies have their expiration set (the AccountOptions RememberMeLoginDuration is also set to 365 days).  Both "idsrv" and "idsrv.session" still have a 1969 expiration.

Comment: were you actually able to find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same....

Comment: solved the issue (at least in my case) - are you using their sample "Quickstart" UI login page?

Comment: @JakeJ how are you getting id_token?

Answer (score 5):

You can configure Identity Server's authentication cookie lifetime when you register Identity Server in your `Startup.cs`, like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
})
```

Note: you also need to indicate that the cookie should be persistent when logging the user in. If you're using the Quickstart UI, then you have to tick the "Remember me" checkbox on the login screen to get a persistent cookie. Or you can modify the code to always issue a persistent cookie - something like this:

```
HttpContext.SignInAsync(subject, name, new AuthenticationProperties{ IsPersistent = true});
```

Comment: I've done that, that's what I'm looking at right now with:  options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = new TimeSpan(364, 0, 0, 0); but when I open developer tools in Chrome, the expiration of the "idsrv" cookie is still set to a date in 1969.

Comment: I wonder if the .AddOpenIdConnect() block of code that comes with the AddIdentityServer is overwriting the expiration on it?

Comment: There's actually two cookies, idsrv.session and idsrv, but both still have 1969 as the expiration date.

Comment: I'm debugging through the IdentityServer4 source as it's taking options in.  I see that it sees I'm giving it the expiration.  Now, the cookie that comes out still is already expired / browser session based (for the "idsrv" cookie).  I feel like I'll eventually submit a pull request and find out they did that on purpose.  Does it work for you?

Comment: Interesting. What does your login code look like? Are you making the cookie persistent when signing the user in?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something here.  My client cookie is named simply "Cookies" right now.  I've set that expiration successfully. Your comment makes me think that I should attempt to link it with the idsrv.session cookie or something.  I don't know how all the cookies relate to each other.

Comment: The "Cookies" cookie belongs to your client application. It gets set after after the OpenId Connect middleware authenticates the user with the IdentityServer. The "idsrv" cookie belongs to the Identity Server. It gets set after the user authenticates to the IdentityServer. The two cookies don't need to be linked.

Comment: The client cookie "Cookies" has been set persistent.  How would you go about setting the server cookies "idsrv" or "idsrv.session" persistent?  I see the options to set "idsrv" sliding and the expiration, but it's being ignored.

Comment: Are you using the Quickstart UI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167119/discussion-between-jakej-and-peter).

Comment: @JakeJ I'm experiencing this exact same issue since upgrading from .net core 2.0 to 2.1 and wondering if you were able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does anybody find solution for this problem?

Comment: @Peter options.Authentication.CookieLifetime is not available in IdentityServer4

Answer (score 0):

I set the IdentityServer cookie configuration by using the following code. When I then store the cookie via (rememeber me) option in IdentityServ

```
 // Set identity cookie options
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
 {
     options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
     options.SlidingExpiration = true;
     options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
 });
```