# How to change ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookie expiration?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using ASP.NET Core with Identity Server and Open Id Connect as described [here](https://github.com/onelogin/openid-connect-dotnet-core-sample/blob/master/Startup.cs). I need to change the time of authentication cookie expiration when the Remember Me option is set (14 days by default). I can see that the cookie named ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" is responsible for that. I'm trying to set the expiration like this:

```cs
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
})
```

But it affects another cookie named ".AspNetCore.Cookies" (containing the same token value), which has Session expiration and doesn't seem to do anything. All the ways to change expiration that I found modify only the ".AspNetCore.Cookies" cookie, I couldn't find any way to modify the ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookie. (By the way, the `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` method isn't triggered for me at all for some reason).

Could anyone please explain what the difference is between these two cookies and how I can modify the ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" expiration?

My code in `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // ...
})

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.UserPolicy, policyBuilder =>
    {
        // ... 
    });
});

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "<authority>";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.ClientId = "<id>";
    options.ClientSecret = "<secret>";
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    // ...
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have problems. Like I said, setting options in `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` method isn't called for me at all.

Comment: I added the code to the question. Can the reason be the sequence with which `AddMvc`, `AddAuthentication` and `ConfigureApplicationCookie` are called?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to use Identity at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Identity, doesn't call `AddIdentity`? it uses OIDC as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Gets an authentication token from IdentityServer (OpenIdConnectOptions.Authority). There's also a link to an example I used in the beginning of the question.

Comment: The ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookie is used by Identity. As you're not using Identity, it's not clear why you have this cookie at all. Perhaps you should be looking in your Identity Server project, which I guess _is_ using Identity and setting that cookie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IdentityServer4 how to set server cookie expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367156/identityserver4-how-to-set-server-cookie-expiration)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Kirk Larkin said ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookie is probably set by the Identity Server application that make use of Asp.Net Identity.
So if you want to manage the user session on the IS4 app you need to configure it there.

IS4 application: ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookie.

If you use Identity to configure the cookie as persistent you need to set the expiration when you sign in the user.

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties {
  IsPersistent = true,
  ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
};
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userId, userName, props);
```

If you don't set `IsPersistent=true` then the cookie has session lifetime and you can set the contained authentication ticket expiration like this:

```
.AddCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "idsrv_identity";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
  });
```

Your client application: : ".AspNetCore.Cookies" cookie.

`services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` isn't called because if you use `.AddCookie(...)` this takes the precedence. The options are the same.

This set the app cookie as *session*.

```
.AddCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "myappcookie";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
  });
```

A way to make the app cookie persistent using OIDC is to set the expiration in the `OnSigningIn` event in *AddCookie*.

```
options.Events.OnSigningIn = (context) =>
{
    context.CookieOptions.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

A note about user session.

Every situation is different, so there isn't a best solution, but remember that you have to take care of two user session. One on the IS4 app and one on your client app. These can go out of sync. You need to think if a persistent user session on your client app make sense. You don't want that your user remains logged in your client app when the central SSO (single sign-on) session is expired.

Comment: how this works for external users ? _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(loginProvider, providerKey, isPersistent: false, true); is the method that does not contain parameter to set expiration time as like for local users

Comment: @GopalZadafiya This example use IdentityServer so the external login is managed in the IdentityServer app not in the client. But in general you can set the expiration in configuration, for example in AddIdentity if you use Identity or in AddCookie or AddCookieAuthentication. Never used external login, so I can't be more specific, check the asp.net core docs.

Answer (score 7):

After scrambled through the both `AspNetCore 3.1` & `IdentityServer 4.0.4` repo,
I found the working way to set default authentication cookie option .

TD;LR:

```
    // in Startup.ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
    services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, option =>
    {
        option.Cookie.Name = "Hello"; // change cookie name
        option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); // change cookie expire time span
    });
```

Full Setup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // cookie policy to deal with temporary browser incompatibilities
        services.AddSameSiteCookiePolicy();
        services.AddDefaultAllowAllCors();

        // setting up dbcontext for stores;
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(ConfigureDbContext);

        services
            .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // read clients from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54892390/4927172
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/identity/account/login";
            options.IssuerUri = _configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:IssuerUri");
        })

            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddConfigurationStore<ApplicationConfigurationDbContext>(option => option.ConfigureDbContext = ConfigureDbContext)
            .AddOperationalStore<ApplicationPersistedGrantDbContext>(option => { option.ConfigureDbContext = ConfigureDbContext; })
            .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication()
            .AddProfileService<ApplicationUserProfileService>();

        services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, option =>
        {
            option.Cookie.Name = "Hello";
            option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        });
        services.AddScoped<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<SmsOption>(_configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // use this for persisted grants store
        InitializeDatabase(app);

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseDefaultAllowAllCors();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>

        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if (response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized ||
                response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)
                response.Redirect("/identity/account/login");

            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "Get" && response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
            {
                response.Redirect("/index");
            }
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line before `services.AddAuthentication` is what worked for me eventually with IS4, taken from [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12233):

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x =>
{
       x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the sample `AuthSamples.Cookies` of the Github aspnetcore sources.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
```

...

```
        // Example of how to customize a particular instance of cookie options and
        // is able to also use other services.
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, ConfigureMyCookie>();
    }

internal class ConfigureMyCookie : IConfigureNamedOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>
{
    // You can inject services here
    public ConfigureMyCookie()
    {
    }

    public void Configure(string name, CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        // Identityserver comes with two cookies:

        // Identity.Application
        // Identity.External

        // you can change the options here
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
        }
    }

    public void Configure(CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
        => Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
}
```