# How android native application keep logged in state with identity server 4?

Tags: react-native, identityserver4

I have created react native application for android. Our API are created in .Net core and protected with identity server 4. Right now, I have to re-login every time while user reopen the application.

I want to keep user login untill user doesn't force logout.

Answer (score 0):

Do verify that the session cookies from both your client application and from IdentityServer is persisted in the browser.

For example, in this screenshot from the cookies from IdentityServer, you see that they only last the current session:

[image]

You can find this information in the browsers developer console.

Please notice that you have two session cookies, one from your client application and one from IdentityServer. Ideally, you should set the expiretime
on both cookies.

See these questions:

- [IdentityServer4 how to set server cookie expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367156/identityserver4-how-to-set-server-cookie-expiration)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0