# Net Core Authorize Property Ignore Authentication Cookie Expiration

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using OpenId provider to authenticate my NetCore 6 Razor MVC application. Following my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(cookie => {
        cookie.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
        cookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8);
        cookie.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8);
        cookie.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        cookie.SlidingExpiration = false;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        ...
    });
```

and my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Test()
{
     return View();
}
```

I hope my controller will redirect to login page after 9 minutes or more without activity but it keep ignoring cookies expiration (8 minutes) and show my test page. What went wrong on my code?

Comment: Are you saying that the cookie expiration setting doesn't take effect? Or is the event not automatically triggered when the time comes?

Comment: the cookies expiration setting doesn't take effect and i think it causing the re-login not trigerred

Comment: [Please check this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49337801/7687666)